# Spring - Loading Services and Repositories from dependant JAR file

Tags: spring, service, jar, components

I'm working on a web project and standalone app project that use the same database (using hibernate).  Both are based on Spring and use Services and Repositories.  Since both projects often get to interact with the same entities, i used to have a copy of almost each Repository and Service in each project which was a mess to maintain.  I decided to create a third project and put all the common code in it.  I am then adding the resulting jar file as a local maven dependency but i'm getting errors compiling something that used to work perfectly fine when the code was "local".  This was my old component scan annotation :

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.mdenis.mdhis_webclient")
```

The new classes (same code in different package in a jar file) are in a different package so I am now trying this :

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.mdenis.mdhis_common")
```

There are still local beans that I need to load from the old local package so i will eventually need to get the component scan to check 2 different packages but for now i'm just trying to get this to find my services and repositories in their new "external" location.  I'm getting this exception when running the web app :

```
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:441)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:740)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:716)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:703)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:619)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:491)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1641)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor23.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:287)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1557)
at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:978)
at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:344)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:619)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestFilterValve.process(RequestFilterValve.java:348)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve.invoke(RemoteAddrValve.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:651)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:417)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:754)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1376)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lcom/mdenis/mdhis_common/service/UserService;
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1916)
at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:110)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadFieldsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:262)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationFilterAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:108)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:65)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:328)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:778)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:299)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5003)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
... 41 more

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mdenis.mdhis_common.service.UserService
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1275)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1104)
... 54 more
```

It's only complaining about UserService but i have about 30 services in this app and i'm pretty sure it's having issues finding all of them.  Am i doing something wrong to make this work?  The jar file is correctly loaded in Netbeans and the package structure is correct.

*** EDIT ***

This is the part of my POM.xml that loads the jar i compiled in my third project.  It is correctly being added into the project and the hundreds of classes who depend on these classes have no errors :

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.mdenis</groupId>
        <artifactId>MDHIS_Common</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/MDHIS_Common.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
```

Regards

Comment: You have ClassNotFoundException. Your jar is not loading correctly

Comment: I added it as a local dependency and it is indeed showing under Dependencies in Netbeans with the correct package structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.  the system scope for Maven assumes you will be providing the classes yourself.  I installed my jar into my local Maven repository and removed the scope and systemPath attributes.  Everything now compiles perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

What if you just change your component scan to

`@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.mdenis")`

or

`@ComponentScan({"com.mdenis.mdhis_webclient","com.mdenis.mdhis_common"})`

Then both packages will be scanned.

Comment: Great idea, same exact stack trace unfortunately.  I'm not finding a way to debug this since the execution does not reach any breakpoint i set.

Comment: Upvoted your answer since it did indeed solve my multiple component scan issue!